# How can I prevent saving products duplicated by name in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a client that wants to prevent duplicated products creation in Prestashop.

Hiding the duplicate button is easy but he wants that the system prevent the saving of any new product entry that already had the exact same name added before.

Any idea about how I may achieve this easily?

Or any idea about which file I should edit?

I am using Prestashop 1.6.1.

Comment: "Which file I should edit?" - This isn't a good way to think about editing Prestashop. But it can be extended, overridden with modules, overrides. You need to add your own new files.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to create a new custom module and use hook `actionObjectProductAddBefore`.

You need to use this hook inside the module like that:

```
function hookActionObjectProductAddBefore($params)
{
    $params['object']; // this is the product object you are going to save
    // check if the product name is unique
}
```